# Error in cordova When type "cordova build android"

Tags: android, cordova, build

When i do the cordova build android in cmd, it gives an error:

```
C:\workspace\two>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configur
ation failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:17
6)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.jav
a:599)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.ja
va:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.ja
va:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.d
ispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.d
ispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(Abstract
BroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatc
h.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatc
h.java:30)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocat
ionHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfte
rEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:529)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:90)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(Task
PathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLa
uncher.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:122)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGra
dleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(Exe
cuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildA
ctionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(Contin
uousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(Contin
uousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBu
ild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(
WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute
(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.
execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(For
wardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(
DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClien
t.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBu
ild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(Hin
tGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.
run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(Daemon
StateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.
onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableE
xecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\workspace\two\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version
 19.1.0 or higher.


BUILD FAILED

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
Total time: 3.089 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\workspace\two\platform
s\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\workspace\two\platforms\android\build.grad
le -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

my SDK is complete and path is correct

[image: enter image desciption here]

Cordova Version `6.1.1`
Cordova Platform ls for Android `5.1.1`

Comment: can u attach your config.xml file ??

Comment: @Questi0n As per my knowledge you gotta update your android sdk and build tools.. Also you may have to run the build in verbose mode to get more info on the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496747/illegalstateexceptionbuildtoolsversion-is-not-specified.Check out this link .It resembles like same issue

Comment: please share your config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

when you go through the **CordovaLib** library folder (path: **platforms->android->CordovaLib**) you will find **cordova.gradle** file.

when you go through this file you will find this line: **doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools('19.1.0')**

this line states that **cordova 6.X.X** requires build tools version of 19.1.0 or above to be installed on the system.It wasn't recommended to change it.

As I see through the pic that you have uploaded, I think better way would be to **install 19.1.0 or above**, which wasn't present on your system shown in uploaded pic. Then try **cordova build android** to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi update your config.xml file**

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
        id="ch.papers.test"
        version="1.0.0"
        android-versionCode="1">
```